# How to visualize a subset of $\Bbb{R}P^2$ is homeomorphic to the Möbius band, and how to find the function

Tags: general-topology

Our Homework problem:

Let $S^2$ be the unit sphere in $R^3$. Recall the projective plane is the quotient space $\Bbb RP^2=S^2/\sim$ where $x\sim-x$ (and $x\sim x$) for $x∈S^2$. Show $\Bbb RP^2$ contains a subset that is homeomorphic to the Möbius band.

The hints are consider the "thickened equator" $E⊂S^2$ defined by $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $-1< \phi\ <1$ in spherical coordinates$(r,\theta,\phi)$.

I am also unsure of the hint says. I am the new learner to use laTeX:-)

Comment: If we are to compare a subset of $\Bbb RP^2$ to the Mobius band and show that they are homeomoprhic, we need to have a working definition of the Mobius band so that we have a space to construct a homeomorphism into or out of. So, what is your preferred definition of the Mobius band?

Comment: I suppose you mean the [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip), because the [Mobius band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_Band_(band)) was an electronic rock trio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the image below taken from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) page. You can actually see the right diagram as a subset of the left diagram. This is proof enough for some audiences.

The equator of the sphere gets sent to the vertical line cutting the right diagram in half. The dotted edges correspond to the image of  $\phi=1$, which is the same as the image of $\phi=-1$.

[image]